# Counting duplicate occurrences in Excel with incremental letters instead of numbers

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to make a unique ID out of some duplicate amounts I have in a spreadsheet.

Right now I'm using the below formula.

=COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)&A1

What the formula is doing is attaching a incremental number by count of duplicate occurrences as in the below example:

- Column A
- 295
- 295
- 295
- Column B (Countif formula used)
- 1295
- 2295
- 3295

Which is great but things get tricky and I lose the uniqueness I was hoping to create if my column A has "2295" in row 4 for example:

- Column A
- 295
- 295
- 295
- 2295
- Column B (Countif formula used)
- 1295
- 2295 (Dupe)
- 3295
- 2295 (Dupe)

What I would like to do is add letters incrementing instead of numbers incrementing as I think that would solve my issue. Note just to think ahead but I think it still logically works just by increasing the letters I have some duplicate occurrences of amounts greater or equal to 25.

- Column A
- 295
- 295
- 295
- 2295
- Column B (Countif formula used)
- A295
- B295
- C295
- 2295

Comment: I found the answer, this formula below works nicely. =CHAR(64+COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2))... Ok just noticed zx8754 answer below is the similar as what I found. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=CHAR(64+COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1))&A1
```

`=CHAR(65)` will give you `A`

Comment: Ok so I am reusing this formula on another table that has more then 26 occurences and I noticed after Z, it starts going to lower case letters, then symbols.. Is there anyway for it to continue after Z to AA, AB, AC, etc... instead.

Comment: Hi zx8752, I have accepted your answer, sorry newbie here, I was trying to figure out how I could give you credit. Looks like I can't up vote until I get 15 rep points.

Comment: If you are just trying to make every row id unique try something like this: assuming your id is on `A2` then `B2` is `=RIGHT("00000000000"&A2&"_"&ROW(),10)`

Comment: Hi the formula is great but I need to the same thing in another table to do a join so that I can match the unique IDs. Is there a way so that the count is counting by duplicate occurrences. As is stands now with the new formula the end part is incrementing by number of rows.